# What is equivalent in .net core for context.environment.add?

Tags: asp.net-core

In a .net core app when you want to set a property that is available in all events, what is the same as context.environment.add in previous versions of .net?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about Owin middleware, the context passed in to IApplicationBuilder.Use is of type HttpContext which has an [Items](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions/HttpContext.cs#L56) property which is a dictionary with object keys and values.